# Kendo globalization: different cultures for widgets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, globalization, kendo-asp.net-mvc, culture

I have a `Kendo grid` with `InCell` editing mode and `decimal` column `RATE`.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.ContractCurrencyClauses)
                          .Name("ContractCurrencyClauses")
                          .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Bound(p => p.RATE).ClientTemplate("...").Width(200);                                  
                          })

                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                        .DataSource(dataSource =>
                                                dataSource.Ajax()
                                                .Model(model =>
                                                {
                                                     model.Id(u => u.CONTRACT_ID);
                                                })
                                                .ServerOperation(false)))
```

The problem was when I submitted the form, I always got `null` for `RATE` if it is floating point number because of regional settings on my PC, in case of integer it was ok. I solved the issue by adding globalization in Web.config:

```
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="ru-RU" />
```

But now `en-US` culture affects all kendo widgets, specifically `kendo datepicker`. I tried to apply `ru-RU` culture or format for datepicker editor template, but it does not work:

```
@model DateTime?
<script src="~/scripts/kendo/cultures/kendo.culture.ru-ru.min.js"></script>
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).Culture("ru-RU").Format("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

So, how can I apply `en-US` culture for my `kendo Grid` only?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the something like

```
<script>
     kendo.culture("en-GB");
     var culture = kendo.culture();
     culture.calendar.patterns.d = "dd MMM yyyy"; // short date pattern
     culture.calendar.patterns.D = "dd MMM yyyy"; // long date pattern
     culture.calendar.patterns.t = "HH:mm"; // short time pattern
     culture.calendar.patterns.T = "HH:mm"; // long time pattern
     culture.calendar.patterns.g = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
     culture.calendar.patterns.G = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";
     culture.numberFormat.currency.symbol = "$";
</script>
```

and you can format the number and decimals also.

hope that it will help you